# Laravel 6 in index blade how can I show only users who have roles and their roles in the table

Tags: php, laravel

In index.blade.php, I wrote these codes to show users who have roles

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Roles</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->roles }}</td>
            <td>Show</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

And I wrote these codes in UserController,

```
 $userId = \DB::table('role_user')->get()->pluck('user_id');
 $users = User::find($userId);

 return view('admin.index', compact('users'));
```

And I got these in the website:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"User Administrator","description":null,"created_at":"2021-11-23 03:06:49","updated_at":"2021-11-23 03:06:49","pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}}]

[{"id":2,"name":"Moderator","description":null,"created_at":"2021-11-23 03:06:49","updated_at":"2021-11-23 03:06:49","pivot":{"user_id":2,"role_id":2}}]
```

How can I only display the names in the table role column?

Comment: try this {{ $user->roles->name }}

Comment: if you define eloquent relationship roles in your user model then you can use {{ implode(', ', $user->roles()->pluck('name')->toArray()) }} like that

Comment: I ended up finding the answer myself yesterday! Thanks guys @foreach($user->roles->pluck('name') as $role)
      <li>
            <label>
                      {{ $role }}
             </label>
     </li>
@endforeach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `user->roles`, you're most likely calling towards a relation on your User model. This means that you're returning a collection. If you place a collection in curly braces in blade (`{{ $user->roles }}`), Laravel automatically calls `toArray()` on each model, and a `json_encode` on the result, which results in the JSON strings you end up seeing.

You only want the names, however, so it'd be better to grab those values and convert them to a string. An option of doing so is by [plucking](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values) the `name`, and [imploding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the result:

```php
implode(', ', $user->roles()->pluck('name')->toArray());
```

You have to call `toArray()` on the `pluck()` result, else you'll have a collection instead of an array, which `implode` does not work with.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in and his role is to be displayed, you can use this in your blade:

`{{ Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name') }}`

Or you would like to display the rools of another user, then you can do it as follows:

```
// in Controller fetch the user:
$user = User::find(42);

// in your Blade:
{{ $user->roles->pluck('name') }}
```

In this context, you have a number of methods that you can use:

- roles
- hasRole
- hasAnyRole
- hasAllRoles
- getRoleNames

Comment: You're calling `pluck` on the collection of roles. Since the roles aren't eager loaded, I'd always advise to call `pluck` on the query. (`$user->roles` is a collection of all the user roles, where `user->roles()` is a query call on the relation)